# Java Socket exception while trying to reach .NET WCF web service on IIS

Tags: java, wcf, exception, web-services

When I call, the service's method, I have `Web Service Exception` happening which I couldn't figure out for now.

The issue is this, I am running `NetBeans 6.8` against `IIS 7.0` with the Web Service written using `WCF`:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:151)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
        at $Proxy30.getTwo(Unknown Source)
        at HighBeamWcfClient.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:652)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1072)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:373)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:198)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connection reset" typically means that someone/something between you and the server is resetting the connection or somehow blocking it. Check that you can connect to the server on the port correctly without any issue, and that there are no firewalls in the way.

A very simple test that you can connect to the port in question is to simply telnet to it with `telnet serverhostname portnum`, for example `telnet stackoverflow.com 80`.